Romantic movie - lovers do not know they are related
This is a romantic movie, before 2012. 
It is a romantic movie about a women and a man, and the man's father has dementia/Alzheimers, but in a specific scene in the movie he says "She"(the sons gf) looks like a women he knew. Also to mention he was in the war.
I specifically remember a scene in the movie with her mother saying she was overseas during the war as a nurse or something and she met a man and that man is her father. 
So the movie continues and they fall in love, but what's really getting me is that I think this movie is secretly about incest and the lovers do not know they are related. 

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Are you sure this isn't The Age of Adeline?

There was no incest or dementia but while reading the question, I thought of The age of Adaline too.

Was it possibly Robot & Frank? IMDB says this:

In the near future, Frank is a retired catburglar living alone while his successful son, Hunter, tries to care for him from afar. Finally, Hunter gets him a robot caretaker, but Frank soon learns that it is as useful as a burglary aide. As Frank tries to restart his old profession, the uncomfortable realities of a changing world and his worsening dementia threaten to take beyond what any reboot can do for him.

What they don't mention is that he likes to go to the local library to look at maps of places he's going to break into and the librarian is an attractive older woman that he's smitten with (played by Susan Sarandon). Eventually

Frank breaks into the library at night to steal a rare book to give to the librarian at which point it is revealed that he is her ex-husband but he doesn't remember it. While Sarandon's character does remember they were married, she doesn't say or do anything that reveals this to the audience until near the end.

I don't remember anything about incest in the movie, though. 

To my understanding, this scene is from the movie Friends with Benefits 2011, starring Justin Timberlake and Mila Cunis.
Friends with Benefits released before 2012 ie 2011
For the first part of the question: The father of the character played by Justin, mentions Mila Kunis looks very much like a woman he knew(First time when they meet). This happens at the scene when the father walks up back to the house from the beach with Justin's sister accompanying her.
For the second part: This is a totally different scene, where its bout Mila Cunis's character and how neither she nor her mom was sure who her father was.This conversation takes place at Mila Cunis's house when her mother comes to visit her.

In what way does this meet the questions details?

In what specific way? You don't provide any points of comparison that meet the details in the question.

This is the way it meets the details:
Friends with Benefits released before 2012 ie 2011
For the first part of the question: The father of the character played by Justin, mentions Mila Kunis looks very much like a woman he knew(First time when they meet). This happens at the scene when the father walks up back to the house from the beach with Justin's sister accompanying her.
For the second part: This is a totally different scene, where its bout Mila Cunis's character and how neither she nor her mom was sure who her father was.This conversation takes place at Mila Cunis's house

Then you need to edit those specific details into the answer.

Have edited the ans with these last details.
